# Disable clipboard sync in vino-server?

Tags: clipboard, vino

AFAIK, if someone views my screen the connection uses the `vino-server`.

Is there a way to **disable** synchronizing the clipboards?

`gsettings list-keys org.gnome.Vino` shows various settings, but nothing to disable clipboard sharing.

Thanks